# How to test iOS app's localization on a real device when using appium?

Tags: ios, localization, appium-ios

What are the different options for testing an application's localization (i.e. starting the application in different languages) without changing the application's source code or phones language manually?

In my scenario I would like to test the application with its different localization options using Appium on a real device.

The options that I have found out until now are:

1) Setting the device's language and region to a language/region not supported by the application, and then configuring the "Localization native development region" in the Info.plist to the language that you want to start the application with

2) Changing the language manually on the device (not an option)

3) Tweaking the applications source code (found some articles about this but as changing the actual source code is not an option here, didn't evaluate this further)

The option 1 seems like the most promising one but because changing the phones language to one that is not understood is not an option, it does not work in my case as such.

Any ideas how this could be done either using option 1 without changing the phones actual language or using a totally different approach?